# disable ability to save over a document

Tags: template, save

I have a template file that users continuously save over the existing file. Is there a way to lock a file in sharepoint so that it cannot be saved over and users are forced to "save as"?

Answer (score 0):

you change the browser handling method in central admin, after changing it downloads the file to local and you can update the file and upload it back, can you specify what kind of file or document it is ..?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new content type for your document library based on the Document content type.

In the advanced settings of the content type, you can link to an existing template (stored in the Forms folder of the library which is hidden from users) or upload a new template.

And if you only want users to add documents with this template, remove the Document content type from the library.